# Scrape and Download Pdf files with modified names through Beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to download the PDF files from https://www.archives.gov/research/pentagon-papers

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.archives.gov/research/pentagon-papers"

# If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'E:\webscraping'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location): os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# Downloading the files
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    # Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location, link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url, link['href'])).content)
```

However I would like the files to be names not like the file names but as their description. For example I would like the third file in the table to be named `[Part II] U.S. Involvement in the Franco-Viet Minh War, 1950-1954.pdf` and not `Pentagon-Papers-Part-II.pdf`

in the `link` elements of the `for` loop this is stored as `contents` but I do not knwo how to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the text from the `<a>` tag as the name, as you wish?

Here's how:

```python
import os
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.archives.gov/research/pentagon-papers"

# If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'E:\webscraping'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):
    os.mkdir(folder_location)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

# Downloading the files
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    filename = os.path.join(
        folder_location,
        (
            link.getText()
            .rstrip()
            .replace(" ", "_")
            .replace(",", "")
            .replace(".", "")
        ),
    )
    with open(f"{filename}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url, link['href'])).content)
```

That should produce the files as they're described:

```
E:\webscraping/Index
E:\webscraping/[Part_I]_Vietnam_and_the_US_1940-1950
E:\webscraping/[Part_II]_US_Involvement_in_the_Franco-Viet_Minh_War_1950-1954
E:\webscraping/[Part_III]_The_Geneva_Accords
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_A_1]_Evolution_of_the_War_NATO_and_SEATO:_A_Comparison
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_A_2]_Evolution_of_the_War_Aid_for_France_in_Indochina_1950-54
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_A_3]_Evolution_of_the_War_US_and_France's_Withdrawal_from_Vietnam_1954-56
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_A_4]_Evolution_of_the_War_US_Training_of_Vietnamese_National_Army_1954-59
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_A_5]_Evolution_of_the_War_Origins_of_the_Insurgency
E:\webscraping/[Part_IV_B_1]_Evolution_of_the_War_Counterinsurgency:_The_Kennedy_Commitments_and_Programs_1961

and more ...
```